# How to check if id exists in another table given table is 30 million records?

Tags: mysql, performance, bigdata

I know the question seems duplicate, but I don't know how to ask it differently.

I have two very simple tables in MySQL database, The first is table `Users`

```
id,   user_id
 1       1
 2       3
 4       4
```

The second is table Friends

```
id,    user_id,    friend_id
 1        1             3
 2        1             4
 3        1             8
```

I dumped the data from CSV file that I would like to clean. I need to check if friend_id exists in table 1 as well. The first table has around 30000 rows, but the second table has around 30 million rows.

And I use this query to check

```
SELECT u.user_id, uf.friend_id as exists_friend_ids
FROM Users u, Friends uf
WHERE u.user_id = '1'
    and uf.friend_id IN (select user_id from eventify.Users)
```

However, my desired output would be this but as I cannot run the above query to actually give my test results I cannot continue.

```
user_id,   exists_friend_ids
    1            3
    1            4
```

You can see that 8 is not there, because it doesn't exist in Users table. But as the second table has over 30 million records it's just running forever on my computer. Am I doing it right or this is the only way to do it. Or should I learn Hadoop instead?

I have updated my query to use equal join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a LEFT JOIN query with a GROUP BY friend_id ? If a user doesn't exist, it won't add a line to the result.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but right now any query that I try wouldn't give any result because it's really slow.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is cleaning the table then you have some flexibility since the fact that the query runs slow will not have a great impact since you will want to run it only once. Here are a couple of different options:

1. use a left join to find the rows in friends without the corresponding friend id in the users table (untested):

   SELECT Friends.id, Users.user_id
   FROM Friends LEFT JOIN Users on Friends.friend_id = Users.user_id
   WHERE Users.user_id is NULL

   Then delete the records you find
2. use an inner join to fin the friends that exist. Then create a new table with those records (untested)

   SELECT Friends.id, Users.user_id
   FROM Friends INNER JOIN Users on Friends.friend_id = Users.user_id

   And insert the resulting rows into a new table which will become your new "Friends" table.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you do the CASE construct here. If you want to get a list of all friend_ids that don't exist in the users table, then what about something like:

```
select friends.friend_id,
       count(*) 
  from friends
 where friends.friend_id not in (select users.user_id
                                   from users)
 group by 1
```

You will of course have an index on users.user_id...